# Compactly supported sigmoid-like function (pursuit of closed-form expression)

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

**Introduction:**

This question concerns the existence, uniqueness and most importantly the expression (closed form or otherwise) of a compactly supported sigmoid-like function, whose derivative has the same shape as the function. This function has many practical applications due to its property of being compactly supported while also yielding well-behaving derivatives of high orders.

**Description:**

Suppose $f$ is a real function that satisfies

1. $f(-1) = -1$, $f(1) = 1$
2. $f$ has continuous derivatives of all orders
3. $f$ has $n$'th derivatives $f^{(n)}(-1) = f^{(n)}(1) = 0$ for any integer $n > 0$
4. $f'\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right) = f(x)+1$, $x \in [-1,1]$

It can be assumed that $f(x)=-1$ for $x \le -1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x \geq 1$.

We wish to obtain a closed-form expression of $f$

No successful attempts have yet been made in obtaining any closed or computable form of $f(x)$. Instead we present the function obtained numerically, depicting it with its derivatives **(figure 1)** and comparing it with closely related functions **(figure 2)**.

[image: f(x) and its derivatives]

The bold line illustrates that $f(x)$ is identical to its first derivative scaled in $x$ (visualization of [4.]).

It is possible to construct various compactly supported sigmoid-like functions by combining a regular sigmoid function such as $erf(x)$ and $tanh(x)$ with an argument that diverges at $x=-1$ and $x=1$. Indeed $f(x)$ is an antiderivative of a class of functions called [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) with more references documenting their construction.
We provide examples of two functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ that do not satisfy [4.] comparing them to the numerically obtained $f(x)$

[image: Comparison to similar function]

Any suggestions or ideas for obtaining the closed-form expression of $f$ or methods to compute efficiently its function values are appreciated.

Comment: If $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ then it's domain is $\Bbb R$ which contradicts the first condition of the domain been $[0,1]$

Comment: Conditions $1$ and $5$ imply $f$ is decreasing, which I'm pretty sure is not what you want.

Comment: The 5th condition seems wrong. If you plug in $x=-1$ you get $-1 = f(-1) = f'(-1) + 1 = 0 +  1 = 1$.

Comment: Existence and uniqueness are rather trivial (just notice that recovering $f$ from its derivative gives you a contraction on $C_{\text{odd}}([-1,1])$ equipped with the usual $\max$ norm with the contraction factor $1/2$). A closed formula is almost certainly out of question, but we can think a bit about how to compute its values fast at any particular point up to the given precision.

Comment: Why would you insist on keeping $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ if you're only interested in a bijection of  $[0,1]$? Are you trying to obfuscate your own question?

Comment: @fedja Thanks. I think you are right. It would indeed be valuable to be able to compute the function values efficiently. I still have a faint hope that a closed form may exist due to the simple structure of the function. Perhaps there is a way to prove that it does not?

Comment: @jjagmath It was just to imply that the function was not restricted outside the interval. But I think you are right that it is not helpful. Additionally, the range and domain is actually redundant provided $f(-1) = -1$ and $f(1) = 1$. Will simplify that.

Comment: If the function was not restricted outside the interval the uniqueness was of course out of the question.

Comment: The conditions imply that the function is not analytic in any dyadic rational. I'd take that as a hint that a closed form don't exists.

Comment: @jjagmath #1 absolutely correct. #2 I am unsure how that conclusion is reached. it is very likely that you are right, but several closed form functions (in addition to $g(x)$ and $h(x)$) comes remarkably close to the desired $f(x)$. If you are indeed right, then it may be necessary to pursue ways of approximating the function values instead.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for the comments:

I still need to check this with more detail, but I think the idea is right.

Lets assume $f$ is odd.

Set $x=1$ in $f'(\tfrac{x-1}{2})=f(x)+1$ we get $f'(0)=2$.

Deriving $n-1$ times we get $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}f^{(n)}(\tfrac{x-1}{2}) = f^{(n-1)}(x)$. Setting $x=1$ we get $f^{(n)}(0) = 2^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(1) = 0$ for $n\ge 2$.

Now set $x=0$ to get $f'(-\tfrac{1}{2})=1$ and $f''(-\tfrac{1}{2})=2 f'(0)=4$ and $f^{(n)}(-\tfrac{1}{2}) = 2^{n-1}f^{(n-1)}(0) = 0$ for $n\ge 3$.

Since $f$ is odd we get $f'(\tfrac{1}{2})=1$ and $f''(\tfrac{1}{2})=-4$ and $f^{(n)}(\tfrac{1}{2}) = 0$ for $n\ge 3$.

Now set $x=\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{-1}{4},\tfrac{3}{4}\ldots$. All the derivatives will be $0$ from some point on. This means that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series around that points is $0$.

Comment: This appears to be correct. Suppose that this is correct and that (and that it is sufficient to show that this is true for the rationals), does the zero radius of convergence prove that the function does not have a closed form? I probably misunderstood a part of the argument as I reckon infinitely differentiable functions (with or without closed form) only yields Taylor series approximating individual points regardless?

Comment: Well, I never claimed that this proves that there's not closed form, but this make it very unlikely. In fact, "having a closed form" doesn't have a precise mathematical definition, so we can't expect a proof. But the intuitive concept of closed form will probably need an algebraic combination of elementary functions or even some of the called "special functions" (gamma, the error function, the Bessel functions, the Lambert W function, the elliptic integrals, functions like $Ei$, $Ci$, etc.) but then the function will be analytic in its domain, which we can discard by the argument I gave.

Comment: @jjagmath If you consider the standard bump functions as having a "closed form" (albeit piecewise), then you can have closed forms that are not analytic on their domain. However, I think the fact that there is a dense set of points at which the function in the question is nonanalytic means the function is nonanalytic everywhere (points of analyticity form an open set). I am hard pressed to think of any way to make a "closed form" expression that is nonanalytic everywhere.

Comment: @jet457 That was the point of my comment (its not really an answer): to point out that is not analytic in a dense set.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the first order derivative and call it $w = f'$. It is a compactly supported bell shaped function.

$$
\forall x \in \left[-1, 1 \right], \quad w'(x) =C \left( w(2x+1) - w(2x-1) \right)\tag{*}\label{FuncEq}
$$

As such it admits a Fourier transform $\hat{w}$. From Eq.\eqref{FuncEq}
\begin{align}
2\pi i \xi \hat{w}(\xi) &=  \frac{C}{2}  \hat{w}\left(\frac{\xi}{2} \right)\left( e^{\pi i \xi} - e^{-\pi i \xi} \right)\\
&= i C \hat{w}\left(\frac{\xi}{2} \right)\sin(\pi  \xi)
\end{align}
it implies that we must necessarily have $C=2$.

By induction:
\begin{align}
\hat{w}(\xi) &=  \hat{w}\left( \frac{\xi}{2^{N+1}} \right) \prod_{n=0}^N\mathrm{sinc}\left( \frac{ \xi}{2^{n}} \right)
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{sinc}$ is the cardinal sine defined by:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}
\end{equation}
And then
\begin{align}
\hat{w}(\xi) &=  \hat{w}\left( 0 \right) \prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{sinc}\left( \frac{\xi}{2^{n}} \right)
\end{align}
As
\begin{align}
\mathrm{sinc}\left( \xi\right) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left( \frac{\pi \xi}{2^{k}} \right)
\end{align}
we also have:
\begin{align}\label{eq:what}
\hat{w}(\xi) &=  \hat{w}\left( 0 \right) \prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{sinc}\left( \frac{\xi}{2^{n}} \right)\\
&=\hat{w}\left( 0 \right) \prod_{n=0}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left( \frac{\pi \xi}{2^{k+n}} \right)\\
& = \hat{w}\left( 0 \right) \prod_{h=1}^\infty \cos^{h}\left( \frac{\pi \xi}{2^{h}} \right)
\end{align}
$w$ being compactly supported in $\left[-1, 1 \right]$ it can be extended into a periodic function of period $2$ and, as it is smooth, $w$ is equal to its Fourier extension on $\left[-1, 1 \right]$. The Poisson summation formula yields:
\begin{align}
w(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{w}\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)e^{\pi i k x}
\end{align}
That can be simplified further but that is the idea.

More details here:
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4665218